# Saving an arbitrary array of bytes as a string

Tags: c#

I've got a bunch of data that I need serialized into a string to be stored in a KVP. I've got tons of `ints`, `bools`, and `floats`. I take each one, BitConverter it into a `byte[]` that I am `Buffer.BlockCopying` into a single large `byte[]`.

I need to save this large array of bytes as a string in a `KeyValuePair<string, string>`. I tried using `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()` with the big `byte[]` I created, and then I tried to reload my level with the string code achieved using `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()`.

```
m_LevelCode = Encoding.ASCII.GetString( bytes );
```

The array of bytes has tons of 0's, so I'm guessing that's why my `m_LevelCode` string is an empty string.

Is there a better approach to what I'm trying to do? I have about 650 bytes worth of `integers`, `booleans`, and `floats`. I need them to be saved into a string. One step further, I'd like to comma separate 5 of these into a single KVP to conserve on individual keys since every area has 5 levels.

Comment: Note that ASCII doesn't allow for arbitrary octets to be encoded within it (it's a 7-bit charset).  You probably want to use base64 or similar at some point if you want this to be a proper ASCII string.  I'm no C# expert (never used it, in fact), but that may be the reason for some/all of the zeroes--they are just bytes that can't encode directly in ASCII.

Comment: Thanks BJ, I'll need to do a couple more tests but at first glance that looks like that might be the problem!

Comment: If you decode 0 as ASCII, you'll get U+0000 in your string. The length of `m_LevelCode` should be the same as `bytes` because UTF-16 encodes any character that ASCII can provide as one code unit (`char`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to convert the bytes to a string

```
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

string hex = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);

var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = jss.Serialize(bytes);
```

where `bytes` is byte array.